# Acessar uma mesma página em mútiplos "pathname"

Tags: php

Estou criando umas páginas para um site que mostraria o perfil de uma determinada pessoa utilizando um caminho no url (pathname)

Exemplo:

- demo.com/page/IagoBruno
- demo.com/page/RodriggoDell

Todos esses domínios mostrariam a mesma página (em php) e nessa página seria colocado um código para buscar informações do perfil citado nesse caminho do url, no caso: IagoBruno ou RodriggoDell.

Comment: O que você pesquisou/tentou até aqui ?

Comment: Eu não sei como pesquisar isso, meio que sou novo em php, mas acho que é assim que redes sociais fazem com os perfis dos usuários: mesmas páginas e conteúdo diferente.

Comment: veja a resposta do Rodrigo, é bem nessa linha. Na verdade quem faz a mágica é o webserver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mod_rewrite`. Como isso você poderá redirecionar as requisições de:

`demo.com/page/IagoBruno` para `demo.com/page.php?username=IagoBruno`

ou:

`demo.com/page/RodriggoDell` para `demo.com/page.php?username=RodriggoDell`

Nesse caso em especial, a configuração do mod_rewrite ficaria assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+) /page.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Obviamente o módulo deverá estar habilitado no Apache.

Comment: Esse código ficaria no arquivo .htaccess?

Comment: Pode ficar tanto na configuração do virtual host quando do .htaccess, desde que o AllowOverride esteja habilitado

Comment: Deu certo aqui, obrigado! =)

Comment: De nada! Não se esqueça de validar a resposta. :)